# Image of source/sink in fluids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am confused in questions of fluid flow involving boundaries. Let's say, there is a source of fluid of strength $m$ at $(0,0)$ i.e origin. And both y-axis & x-axis are rigid boundaries. Is this system equivalent to a source of strength $3m$ at $(0,0)$  but without boundaries?

Comment: Does the entire flow go into the 1st quadrant?  If so, it is the same as putting  a source of 4m at the origin with no boundaries.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I have certain doubts in image system with respect to a plane, given in the following question. https://books.google.co.in/books?id=nRkkdxfgTOQC&lpg=SA5-PA45&ots=NSDJa-nSVR&dq=IN%20THE%20region%20bounded%20by%20a%20fixed%20quadrantal%20arc&pg=SA5-PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false . Why is there no image of source A in the plane OA & also of sink B in the plane OB. @ChetMiller

Comment: Which problem are you looking at in the link?

Comment: Ex.4 on page 5.48

Comment: I don't understand why they are using sources and sinks at the origin.  But for the source at x=a, putting an image source at x=-a guarantees no flow from this source through the y axis.  And using double the source is necessary because half the flow has to go to the upper half-plane and half has to go to the lower half-plane.  Then I would use similar reasoning for the sink at y = b.

Comment: They are using at the origin because of circular boundary ( milne Thompson theorem)

Comment: I don't see anything in the problem statement about a circular boundary.

Comment: The rigid boundary consists of circular quadrant, plane OA and plane OB

Comment: That’s what I assumed in my description.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to construct the images of the source located at $(x,y) = (a,a)$ and taking a limit of the solution $a\rightarrow 0$.

The idea behind the method of images is that we construct a system in which flows across the boundaries are removed by the symmetry argument.

In this problem, you need not two but three image sources to compensate flows across the boundaries. If you did not add the source 4, some fluid from sources 2 and 3 would flow into area 4, thus destroying the symmetry between 1 and 2, and 1 and 3.

Therefore a solution would be to consider 4 times as strong source located in a system without boundaries. It also makes sense intuitively: the system with boundaries is 1/4 of the system without.

One more remark: method of images has its assumptions. I believe your flow should be non-viscous and have vanishing curl.

[image: Blue dot is the physical source, red ones are images. Area 1 is physical.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please refer to my comment on the question for more details.

Comment: I cannot comment under your post there yet ;)

I believe the textbook is wrong. I mean their text about images is right, but the picture they give is wrong. They say that images with respect to the boundaries should be of magnitude $m/\pi$. So all sources/sinks strengths in the picture (and in further calculations) should be twice as high.